# Remove hyperlink from Kendo UI MVC Grid export

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, export-to-excel, kendo-asp.net-mvc, export-to-pdf

Does anyone know of a way to remove hyperlinks in the file generated from Kendo UI grid *export to PDF and Excel* functionality?

I have customised the export a fair amount and removed the pager bar etc, using CSS.

However I cannot work out how to stop the column headers from being hyperlinks.

I have tried setting the

```
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
```

but that didn't help and I am trying to avoid using javascript to remove it where possible.

**UPDATE**
Please see below an edited version of my grid code.

```
  @(Html.Kendo().Grid<MvcProject.Domain.DTO.Reports.AccidentSummary>()
                    .Name("resultsGrid")
                   .Columns(columns =>
                        {
                            columns.Group(group => group
                                .Title("Accident Summary Report : Date run - " + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() )
                                .Columns(header => {

                                       header.Bound(c => c.DocCount)
                               .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: center;" })
                               .Title(" ")
                               .ClientTemplate("<div><i rel='tooltip' title='Documents Attached' #= DocCount > 0 ? classHasFile : '' #></i></div>")
                               .Width(35).Filterable(false).Sortable(false).Groupable(false).IncludeInMenu(false);
                        header.Bound(c => c.RegionName)
                            .Title("Region")
                            .Width(100);
                        header.Bound(c => c.AreaName)
                          .Title("Area")
                          .Width(200);

   header.Bound(c => c.Date_of_Accident)
                            .Title("Date")
                            .Width(120)
                         .Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}");

                        header.Bound(c => c.Days_Lost)
                            .Title("Days Lost")
                             .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: center;" })
                            .Width(120);


                        header.Bound(c => c.TypeOfAccidentName)
                          .Title("Nature ")
                          .Width(150);

                        header.Bound(c => c.Location_of_Accident)
                            .Title("Location Of Accident")
                            .Width(150).Hidden(true);

                          header.Bound(c => c.Comments)
                            .Title("Comments")
                            .Width(250).Hidden(true);

                                })
                            );
                        })
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 900px;" })
                        .Pageable(p => p
                            .ButtonCount(5)
                            .PageSizes(true)
                            .Refresh(true)
                        )
                        .Scrollable(s => s.Height("auto"))
                        .Sortable()
                        .Filterable()
                        .Groupable()
                        .ColumnMenu()
                        .Resizable(r => r
                            .Columns(true)
                        )
                        .Excel(excel => excel
                            .FileName("Accident Summary.xlsx")
                            .Filterable(true)
                            .ProxyURL(Url.Action("_GridExportSave", "Reports"))
                            .AllPages(true)
                        )
                        .DataSource(d => d
                            .Ajax()
                            .Read(read => read.Action("_AccidentSummaryResults_Read", "Reports").Data("Genesis.Reports.HandS.Search.getPaginationData"))
                            .ServerOperation(true)
                            .PageSize(20)
                        )
                        .ToolBar(tools =>
                        {
                            tools.Pdf();
                            tools.Excel();
                        })
                         //PDF removed for now until it is patched
                        .Pdf(pdf => pdf
                             .AllPages()
                            .FileName("AccidentSummary.pdf")
                            .ProxyURL(Url.Action("_GridExportSave", "Reports"))
                        )
                        .Events(events => events.DataBound("Genesis.Reports.HandS.Search.loadTT"))
                    )
```

Comment: What grid features are enabled (sorting, paging, etc)? What are you using to export the PDF, built in grid functionality or drawing API? What version of Kendo UI are you using?

Comment: Please post your code. What is that you exactly want to achieve? Do you still want the export to display/work or remove it?

Comment: @EdCharbeneau Please see the code above that i've just added. We are using the built in PDF Export and version 2015.2.902

Comment: @rohitreddyk I want the headers to still be displayed on the columns, just don't want them to link away from the PDF.

Comment: @GazWinter found any solution?

Comment: It needs to be working but when I export to Pdf. My Email column becomes email hyperlink. I want it to behave normal column instead of email hyperlink? any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<style>
      .k-pdf-export .k-grid-toolbar,
      .k-pdf-export .k-pager-wrap
      {
         display: none;
      }

</style>
```

or

```
<style>
        .k-grid-toolbar, 
        .k-grid-pager > .k-link 
        { 
          display: none; 
        }

</style>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the solution.

I already have those styles applied to hide the pagers etc, the problem is the column links not the pager links.

Comment: It needs to be working but when I export to Pdf. My Email column becomes email hyperlink. I want it to behave normal column instead of email hyperlink? any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Use `pdf.avoidLinks(true)` to skip the actual hyperlinks.

`pdf.avoidLinks` indicates whether to produce actual hyperlinks in the exported PDF file.

`pdf.avoidLinks` default value is false.

```
 .Pdf(pdf => pdf
         .AllPages()
         .FileName("AccidentSummary.pdf")
         .avoidLinks(true)
         .ProxyURL(Url.Action("_GridExportSave", "Reports"))
          )
```

Note: Available in versions 2015.3.1020 and later

[For reference](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-pdf.avoidLinks)

Comment: It needs to be working but when I export to Pdf. My Email column becomes email hyperlink. I want it to behave normal column instead of email hyperlink? any suggestions?

Comment: @HammadSajid you can change the input type as text

Answer (score -1):

With following you can easily hide excel export button from MVC Kendo Grid

$(".k-grid-excel").hide();